# Braucht man "es" in "es schaffen zu können, was man sich vorgenommen hat"?

Tags: grammar, style

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Denn nur wenn man das Gefühl habe, schaffen zu können, was man sich vorgenommen hat, könne man auch zufrieden sein mit dem, was man tut.

Es kommt mir wie eine Lücke vor, als ich "schaffen zu können" lese: *Was* schaffen zu können? Die Antwort kommt zwar direkt danach, aber ich frage mich, ob es 1) grammatisch und 2) typisch ist, so zu schreiben. Ich finde, es wäre angenehmer zu lesen, wenn man so schreiben würde:

> Denn nur wenn man das Gefühl habe, **es** schaffen zu können, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use "es" in a statement, where it is already defined or not defined afterwards, like in:
"Nur wenn man das Gefühl hat, es schaffen zu können, muss man es überhaupt versuchen."

I don't think "es" is right here, because it isn't defined at that point. You could however use "das".

> Denn nur wenn man das Gefühl habe, das schaffen zu können, was man sich
>   vorgenommen hat, ...

Personally, I would not use "das" though.
If I am not mistaken, "was man sich vorgenommen hat" is a so called "Objektsatz", which functions as the "Akkusativobjekt" of the sentence.

Comment: This, pretty much. You could add a das, but that would put extra emphasis on that what you want to achieve. Which is not desired here. The sentence is correct as is =3

Answer (score 1):

Meinem Erkenntnisstand nach würde hier das "es" nach hinten verschoben und zum "was man sich vorgenommen hat" werden.

Ähnlich ist es bei Sätzen wie:

> Das Abitur zu schaffen.

In denen das "es" durch ein Subjektive ersetzt wird.

Zudem handelt es sich bei deinem Beispiel um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz, deswegen muss dieser strukturell nicht vollständig sein. Das heißt: 1) Grammatisch ist dieser Satz korrekt und 2) wenn man es so ausdrücken wollte würde dies auch die typische Variante sein.

Comment: Im Beispielsatz nimmt **"was"** die Stelle von **"es** ein.